# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `members` on serializer `HealthQuotationSerializer`

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Trying out serialising parent and child model.Here are my models:

```
class HealthQuotation(models.Model):
  quotation_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  insuredpersons = models.IntegerField()
  mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.quotation_no

class HealthQuotationMember(models.Model):
   premium = models.FloatField(null=True)
   suminsured = models.FloatField()
   quotation = models.ForeignKey(HealthQuotation,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
     return str(self.quotation)
```

Here are my serializers:

```
class HealthQuotationMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = HealthQuotationMember
    fields= "__all__"

class HealthQuotationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   members = HealthQuotationMemberSerializer(many=True)

   class Meta:
      model = HealthQuotation
      fields = ['id','members']
```

On Serialising parent model with parent serializer, Django throws error "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `members` on serializer `HealthQuotationSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `HealthQuotation` instance. Original exception text was: 'HealthQuotation' object has no attribute".

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have members field in your model... Try to change your serializer as following and see if it works:

```
class HealthQuotationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   quotation = HealthQuotationMemberSerializer()

   class Meta:
      model = HealthQuotation
      fields = ['id','quotation']
```

Note that I've removed `many=True` because there will be always one object per this data (`ForeignKey`). when you have more than one object such as `Many2Many` you should use `many=True`.

Answer (score 0):

You have "**HealthQuotation**" as a **parent** and "**HealthQuotationMember**" as a **child**.

Now, you have decided to retrieve data from parent "HealthQuotation" 
and its associated children which will come from "HealthQuotationMember", right?

To achieve that you can use Django `SerializerMethodField()`:

Your serializers.py should look like:

```
class HealthQuotationMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HealthQuotationMember
        fields= '__all__'
```

```
class HealthQuotationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    members = serializers.SerializerMethodField() # I am using SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = HealthQuotation
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_members(self, quotation):
        
        q = HealthQuotationMember.objects.filter(quotation = quotation)
        
        serializer = HealthQuotationMemberSerializer(q, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Your views.py

```
class GetHealthQuotationList(ListAPIView):
    
    serializer_class = HealthQuotationSerializer
    queryset = HealthQuotation.objects.all()
```

Your url.py should be:

```
path('get-health-quotation-list', GetHealthQuotationList.as_view()),
```

NOTE: In case you plan to retrieve data from `child` table and find its associated `parent`, then your serializer should be good to go without `many=True` argument.